# ParseFloat html

Tags: html, parsefloat

I am a college student just learning HTML.  The assignment that I have to complete is a simple grade calculator.  There is a single button that calculates everything, and the values go to three empty text fields(total, average, and percentage).  The problem that I am having is the total is calculated and shows up in the field, but the number is followed by [object].  The average field shows NaN and the percentage field remains empty.  Here is my code.

```
      <input type="button" value="Click to calculate" 
      onclick="fullmark = parseFloat(document.getElementById('fullBox').value);
                science = parseFloat(document.getElementById      ('scienceBox').value);
                math = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mathBox').value);
                computer = parseFloat(document.getElementById('computerBox').value);
                english = parseFloat(document.getElementById('englishBox').value);
                History = parseFloat(document.getElementById('historyBox').value);
               total=science+math+computer+english+history;
               average=(total/5);
               percentage=(total/fullmark)*100;
               document.getElementById('totalBox').value=total;
               document.getElementById('averageBox').value=average;
               document.getElementById('percentageBox').value=percentage;">
```

Comment: you have a typo `History` instead of `history`

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote `History` as the variable name first, but then used `history` when computing/assigning the value for `total`, that is a different variable – identifiers in JavaScript *are* case sensitive.

The only reason you don’t get your script aborted with an error about an undefined variable at that point, is that `window.history` exists – it’s the object that keeps the current navigation history of the window. (All global variables are properties of the window object, so that’s what your use of `history` gets resolved to.) And since it’s an object, `[object]` is what you get as result when transferring it into a string context (which happens through the use of `+`, which is both the addition and the string concatenation operator).

Apart from that, writing all that code into an `onclick` handler is kinda terrible style. Go learn how to use proper functions for stuff like this next ;-)